# How to access variables in external SDRAM

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am working on TM4C1294 + ccs 6.0.1 + TI 5.1.9(Compiler).

Reading/Writing variables in 8MB external sdram worked fine for example `g_pui16EPISdram = (uint16_t *)0x60000000;` `g_pui16EPISdram[SDRAM_END_ADDRESS ] = 0xdcba;`
However, as I use "attribute directive" for accessing to external sdram like below:`int abab[20]__attribute__ ((section (".external")));`, the program is not even executed.

".external" is defined .cmd :

```
SDRAM (RWX) : origin = 0x60000000, length = 0x00800000

SECTIONS
{
    .intvecs:   > APP_BASE
    .text   :   > FLASH
    .const  :   > FLASH
    .cinit  :   > FLASH
    .pinit  :   > FLASH
    .init_array : > FLASH

    .vtable :   > RAM_BASE
    .data   :   > SRAM
    .bss    :   > SRAM
    .sysmem :   > SRAM
    .stack  :   > SRAM
    .external : > SDRAM
}
```

Here is my `.map`:

`SEGMENT ALLOCATION MAP`
`60000000    60000000    00000050   00000000    rw-
  60000000    60000000    00000050   00000000    rw- .external`

GLOBAL SYMBOLS: SORTED ALPHABETICALLY BY Name 

`address    name
--------   ----`

`60000000   abab`

In my project, some of "structs" ,that need to be `extern` variables, are declared in one `.h` and defined in one `.c`;however, for test I just simply used `int abab[]`.
I have tried to test with/without "extern" ahead of "attribute directive", in a nutshell both did not work.

How can I access/use extern variables stored in the external sdram?

Comment: what do you mean by: 'program is not even executed'?

Comment: What does the map file say about where that variable is located? Maybe it has actually been located correctly but the issue is with your source?

Comment: The extern keyword tells the linker to look for a definition that is in another source/header file, it has nothing to do with locating variables in different memory spaces.

Comment: using the T.I. DSPs, the peripherals are memory mapped, so each of the peripheral register structs needs an entry in the .cmd file to place that struct (and the enclosed registers) at the proper address.

Comment: I would try to create a new section using `#pragma DATA_SECTION(abab, ".abab_sect");` and then put `.abab_sect` into `>SDRAM` in your `.cmd` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been resolved. `EPI set-up` for SDRAM was required in `boot routine` since boot routines try to initialize global variables before calling main(). `#pragma` and `attribute` directive are not really a matter for using the external sdram.

Thanks for commenting on my question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think there is a misunderstanding on the concepts of using an **external** storage medium to read/write data and usage of **extern** keyword in C programming language.

Here's a simple explanation:

1) According to your code, what you're doing is just setting the starting `g_pui16EPISdram = (uint16_t *)0x60000000` and ending `g_pui16EPISdram[SDRAM_END_ADDRESS ] = 0xdcba` addresses of SDRAM module for memory mapping to get used by the microprocessor. As you can see in the **SECTIONS** block, **.data**, **.bss**, **.sysmem** and **.stack** are defined in **SRAM** ([Static RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory)). Therefore, if you try to move (or to point) the required data, which is obviously needed by the microcontroller for execution, to an external medium, it will not even be executed. Because, microcontroller does not know where to find it and execute it. It is something like plug a USB memory stick into a PC and expecting to boot from it without appropriate BIOS settings. Since BIOS does not know where the bootstrap code is, the PC will not boot from that medium. Target binary address, to be executed, must be known by the processor. And in your case, it has nothing to do with **extern** keyword. You may want to move your program data only, (`int abab[20]` array for example) to **SDRAM** section in your code and make your program reach that external memory region safely as being executed by microcontroller.

2) **extern** keyword is used for declaring external variables that are visible from files other than the one in which they are defined in C programming language. This modifier can be used with all data types like `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, *arrays*, *pointers*, *structures*, *functions* etc. Basically, this keyword informs the compiler that the variable or function has an external linkage and search for that data structure in all incoming source files. Which is also another way to tell the compiler that *"There is a variable or function declared in somewhere and you, compiler, should know this! (actually, linker does the dirty job and you say to compiler that let the linker find it!)" .*  To make an analogy, `extern` can be thought of as opposite to the `static` keyword.

Comment: HI, Thanks for answering. I should have mentioned in my questions. There is a memory map describing which sections are allocated in memories such as SRAM, SDRAM as well as the address of global variables. Why I have tried to test "with/without" `extern` since if I put `extern` with `attribute directive` like `//#pragma  DATA_SECTION(abab,".external"); //extern int abab[20];`, the compiler seems like ignoring `global variable` and does not assign the address for them.  I looked at the data sheet of TI ARM compiler`, but it does not clearly say.

Answer (score 1):

First, the variable you want to place into SDRAM should be statically allocated, usually a global variable.

Then in your source file, declare it as

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION(abab, ".abab_sect")
int abab[20];
```

Then if you add `-m` to your linker options, a .map file will be generated and show you that `abab` symbol is placed into a `.abab_sect` section, which is allocated in a default memory space, probably in SRAM.

Then in your cmd file, add

```
SECTIONS
{
    ...
    ...
    .abab_sect : > SDRAM 
}
```

to move it to SDRAM

Comment: Hi, Thank you for commenting on my questions. I have tried both `#pragma DATA_SECTION(abab, ".abab_sect") int abab[20];` and `int abab[20]__attribute__ ((section (".abab_sect")));`. As I understand, both directive works same. In the `.map` I can clear see the memory address of`abab`, but the program did not execute as I programed `.bin` into the micro controller.

Comment: @Jin If you see `abab` is in SDRAM address space, then at least the SDRAM allocation part works. You might have to strip your program to the minimal and debug it from scratch.