# Placing a global constant array into `.rodata` section

Tags: c, gcc, static

The goal is to place a large array of constant data into `.rodata` section with allowing the access to it from other translation units. As far as I know, GCC would place a data into the read-only section if declared as `static const`. But then it is impossible to declare it as `extern` in other files. For a non-static array I would do something like:
`data.c` will contain:

```
const int data[] = {0,1,2,....}
```

and `data.h` will contain:

```
extern const int data[];
```

It will allow any file including `data.h` to "see" this data. But how would one do about this:

```
static const int data[] = {0,1,2,....}
```

Of course, I can define the target section explicitly, using `__attribute __((section("name"))`, but I prefer to avoid this type of heavy artillery usage.
So what is the most portable and appropriate way of doing the required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no portable way to put data into the `.rodata` section because even the existence of such a section is implementation-dependent.

With that said, you could consider approaching your problem like this:

```
extern const int * const data;

/* ... */

static const int rodata[] = {0,1,2,....};
const int * const data = rodata;
```

Comment: Well, `rodata` is not a must here. The idea is to use program memory rather than data memory (embedded system, limited RAM, but large FLASH...). But I like your idea. It's simple. I should have though about it myself :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this answer:

[What is the use of "#pragma section <XYZ>" in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981580/what-is-the-use-of-pragma-section-xyz-in-c)

discusses the common way to place a specific data item into its' own section in the resulting object file

I have found the '#pragma section ("rodata", "myData")  kind of statement in many compilers.

Note that not every compiler has this #pragma so this method is not completely portable.

Comment: It's the same as using `__attribute((section..` thing which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is only half the answer. If you want to move the data to a memory location, like L1/L2/L3 SRAM, flash, or external DRAM, you need to move those "<XYZ>" sections in the linker command file, or they will go to the default memory location, usually DRAM.  see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784102/how-to-access-variables-in-external-sdram/29798031#29798031